# Docker access localhost in browser

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, adonis.js

I use Docker Compose for Windows and I can't access to localhost:3333 from browser (Windows).

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
data:
    image: mongo:latest
    volumes:
        - "./data:/usr/app/data"
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --logpath=/dev/null # --quiet
web:
    image: rifton007/nodejs
    command: adonis servev --dev
    links:
        - data
    volumes:
        - .:/usr/app/
        - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
        - "3333:3333"
```

In browser with localhost:27017, I can access to Mongo Container.
But localhost:3333 return me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

However, `adonis servev --dev` it's correctly running and when I tried ``curl localhost:3333 in the container, i can see html code of the web page.

Thanks you,

Comment: not seeing you use port 3000 here?

Comment: Oops, it isn't :3000 but well :3333.
I just have corrected my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using the docker machine ip. I have to do the same on my windows 10 box. Run `docker-machine ip` and use that plus your `port` number and see if it works